# PostgreSQL: Showing domain properties using SQL without the Slash Syntax

Tags: postgresql, psql, datagrip

In PostgreSQL, showing the properties of a domain is done using `\dD`, e.g.:

```
\dD dom_reason

             List of domains
Schema |    Name    |     Type      | Modifier |  Check
....
```

In DataGrip, [`\` notation is not yet supported](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-1272). Is there a way to query domain properties using straight SQL?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this:

```
SELECT n.nspname as domain_schema, 
       t.typname as domain_name, 
       pg_catalog.format_type(t.typbasetype, t.typtypmod) as data_type, 
       not t.typnotnull as nullable, 
       t.typdefault as default_value, 
       c.conname as constraint_name, 
       pg_catalog.pg_get_constraintdef(c.oid, true) as constraint_definition, 
       obj_description(t.oid) as remarks 
FROM pg_catalog.pg_type t 
  LEFT JOIN pg_catalog.pg_namespace n ON n.oid = t.typnamespace 
  LEFT JOIN pg_catalog.pg_constraint c ON t.oid = c.contypid 
WHERE t.typtype = 'd' 
  AND n.nspname = 'public' -- change here for your schema name
```

You can easily find the statements that `psql` is using for each of its backslash commands by starting psql with the option `-E` or `--echo-hidden`